# 「sudo」と「sudo -s」の違い

Tags: unix, sudo

**それぞれどういう時に使用するのでしょうか？**
・環境変数は異なるのでしょうか？

**sudo -s**
・「sudo」との違いは、「root権限が必要なコマンドを多く使う場合に、いちいちsudoする必要がなくなる」ことだけですか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo -s`は現在の環境変数を保ったままrootとしてシェルを起動するので、`sudo $SHELL`と同じです。これにコマンドを付け加て`sudo -s '{コマンド}'`とすると`sudo $SHELL -c '{コマンド}'`としている事になります。
なので`sudo`と`sudo -s`の違いですが、コマンドなしでrootシェルを起動する以外の使い方としては「いちいちsudoする必要がなくなる」くらいであってるように思います。
あと考えつくのはrootとしてパイプやリダイレクトできるくらいでしょうか。`sudo -s 'command >> file'`とすればrootでのみアクセスできるファイルに書き込めますが、`sudo command >> file`ではできません。